# FK Constraints on one-to-one

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine, constraints

I have a one-to-one relationship in my MySQL database with two tables, `Event` and `Theme`.

```
ALTER TABLE Event ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FA6F25A359027487 FOREIGN KEY (theme_id) REFERENCES Theme (_uuid) ON DELETE SET NULL;
ALTER TABLE Theme ADD CONSTRAINT FK_56B4C80C71F7E88B FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES Event (_uuid) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I'd like the behaviour that if I delete the theme record, the theme_id is set to NULL, and if I delete the event record, the theme record is also deleted.

However, now when I run DELETE FROM Event, I get this error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`from_dev`.`eventleveltheme`, CONSTRAINT `FK_6E25E16871F7E88B` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `Event` (`_uuid`))
```

Can I not set both of these constraints? Are they somehow conflicting?

Comment: Do you have any data on your tables?

Comment: Yes, there is data there.

Comment: To expand, the theme_ids are a mixture of valid id references and nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular reference going on here- `Event` has an FK to `Theme` and `Theme` has an FK to `Event`. There should only be an FK from one table to another, not both.

I'm guessing here because I don't know exactly what your data is for, but it seems like a "theme" is something that can be used over and over, whereas an event is a one-time thing. So I'd have `Event` have an FK to `Theme`, and delete `Theme`'s FK to `Event`.

Comment: This is the underlying data from an ORM, and I don't want to lose the event member of my Theme object (that's all that's stopping me).

Comment: That doesn't seem right...it seems like each Event should have a Theme, not the other way around. As for the tables, if these two tables are always one-to-one, you could merge them into one table. Or you could make a third table that matches a theme_id to an event_id (less preferable, since this really should be for many-to-many). I think you need to reevaluate your overall data design. If you do it right, you won't have this circular reference problem at all.

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction, I was missing a couple of config options in the ORM resulting in the wrong constraints. Updated as per this config: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Deviation from SQL standards: If ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL recurses to update the same table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like RESTRICT. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL operations. This is to prevent infinite loops resulting from cascaded updates. A self-referential ON DELETE SET NULL, on the other hand, is possible, as is a self-referential ON DELETE CASCADE. Cascading operations may not be nested more than 15 levels deep.